# convert the "Zend_Gdata_YouTube_VideoFeed Object" in JSON String

Tags: zend-framework, json, zend-gdata

I am trying to retrieving data from youtube. it is retuning the data in `Zend_Gdata_YouTube_VideoFeed Object`. How can I convert it in JSON string format...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Zend_Gdata_YouTube_VideoFeed Object
```

it is the object of an class. you have to first convert it into string. then you can convert it into JSON ..